# Can i write the codes in JavaScript again If I have ejected (Detached) the app from expo.?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have to use gif in my Android app for which I may require to detach my expo project.

I had a doubt that if I detach my expo project using expoKit, then can I write codes in JavaScript again as I used to before detaching my expo project? Detaching will create one folder for Android and one folder for iOS so then will I have to tackle them differently or writing JS code work? Please don't redirect me to the expo documentation. I have already read that but it still isn't clear to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ejecting a React Native project only mean that you can now access the native parts of the projects separately as well. It doesn't mean that you cannot write JavaScript anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will my dependencies which I had on expo work or will they stop working?
And also in future can I use expo library again if i need them in future may be

Answer (score 3):

Yes you will be able to write code in JavaScript same as before. The only difference will be that Eject process will expose build and other configurations that previously you cannot control. You will also be able to access/interface with Native modules.

Its always a good idea to take backup or commit everything in Version Control (e.g. GIT) so that you can go back (if required).

Only disadvantage of ejected app is you’ll have to worry about maintaining the native project because native areas will not auto upgrade. If anything goes wrong later during development, you’ll have to get familiar with the native code.

**References:**

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject

https://forums.expo.io/t/crna-eject-vs-expo-detach-pros-and-cons/11257